# Windows MSI installation errors on failing to read the tmp script it generates

Tags: wix, windows-installer

This is a weird MSI failure.

```
MSI (s) (90:10) [12:01:14:331]: Doing action: InstallFinalize
Action 12:01:14: InstallFinalize. 
Action start 12:01:14: InstallFinalize.
MSI (s) (90:10) [12:01:14:331]: Running Script: C:\Windows\Installer\MSID2EA.tmp
MSI (s) (90:10) [12:01:14:331]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding UpdateStarted property. Its value is '1'.
MSI (s) (90:10) [12:01:14:334]: Note: 1: 2265 2:  3: -2147287035 
MSI (s) (90:10) [12:01:14:334]: Machine policy value 'DisableRollback' is 0
MSI (s) (90:10) [12:01:14:335]: Note: 1: 1101 2: C:\Windows\Installer\MSID2EA.tmp 3: 32 
Error 1101. Error reading from file: C:\Windows\Installer\MSID2EA.tmp.  System error 32.  Verify that the file exists and that you can access it.
MSI (s) (90:10) [12:01:17:366]: Product: <the product> -- Error 1101. Error reading from file: C:\Windows\Installer\MSID2EA.tmp.  System error 32.  Verify that the file exists and that you can access it.

Action ended 12:01:17: InstallFinalize. Return value 3.
```

As far as I understand, this tmp file is generated by the installation process itself, so I don't quite understand how it can fail to access it, failing the entire installation because of that.

Rerunning the installer worked just fine, but such random errors are not acceptable, so any tip is appreciated...

The installer was authored using WiX 3.10.

Comment: An anti-virus temporarily locks the newly created file? Just an idea.

Comment: @AlexJ yeah, that could be an option. anything I can do about it in the installer?